# AdMob - RewardedVideoAd - best practice if there is no video available (errorCode = 3)

Tags: admob, ads, rewardedvideoad, admob-rewardedvideoad

I am using `RewardedVideoAd` from AdMob in order to unlock categories in my app, but I am getting almost all the time `onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad` with error code 3 which means there is no video available. 
When using test Ad Unit ID is working fine all the time.
What should I do in this case? I am sure there is nothing wrong with my code, it just that there are not so many rewarded videos in my area. 
I cannot just show a message: try again or came back later. 
What is the best practice if there is no video available?

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be popping up a lot in the [google admob forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-admob-help-forum) lately. 
For some reason, admob ads in our app only gets displayed when we run the release build or install from the play store so perhaps you could publish your app and check after few hours when the ads go live.

However note that, ads won't be available *always*. 
That's why it's a good idea to use mediation to ensure you always have an ad.

You can implement it manually too - We use other ad networks like tapjoy as backfill, so when admob's `#onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad` is fired, we show a rewardedvideo ad from other networks.

Implementing Mediation should be ideal as the process is streamlined. Also check if you have filtered out some ads in the console as that affects fill rate.

Comment: My app is indeed not published in google play and will not ever be... I did not filtered any ads. I started using mediation using steps from here: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/  I included AdColony, Chartboost, InMobi and TapJoy and I started receiving ads only from TapJoy - but again not all the time...